# MVCContrib Portable Area No Intellisense for ViewPage<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

I am trying out portable areas using MVCContrib. 
In general these work well and it seems to be a good way to share controllers\views between web projects.

The only problem that I'm having is that Intellisense (specifically, for the HtmlHelper) is not working in the view for strongly typed views i.e. ViewPage. 
The intellisense does work however when the view is a plain 'ol System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage

A similar questions has been asked here:
[MvcContrib Portable Areas View Intellisense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837288/mvccontrib-portable-areas-view-intellisense)

But these suggestions don't seem to make any difference.

I am using MVC 2, the portable areas are in their own class library as in the MVCContrib sample code.
I'd also like to add that the MVC sample code gives me the same behaviour, if I change the sample project to make the view page strongly typed then intellisense stops working.

Are other people having the same problem ?

Does anyone know the cause and or solution ?

the web.config from my Views folder is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*"
          type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: edit, sorry link was wrong , just changed that

Comment: Please show us the web.config for the 'views' folder.

Comment: What type of project are your views in?

Comment: Views are in a class library. The build action is as an embedded resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with ReSharper intellisense in VS2010, ReSharper v5.0.
If I change my ReSharper options (ReSharper->Options->Intellisense->General) to use Visual Studio intellisense then it works!!